# Google App Engine Blobstore stores Blobs but generates invalid Keys!? What is wrong in my Code?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

I want to upload a file, store it in the Blobstore and then later access it (via the BlobKey) but this won't work.

Here is my Code:

```
public class CsvToBlobstoreUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

private final BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

@Override
public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
    final BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("upload");

    final BlobInfo info = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request).get("upload"));

    if (blobKey == null) {
        res.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        res.sendRedirect("/csvupload?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
    }

}

@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key")));
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Language", "en");
    resp.getWriter().println("<blob-key>" + blobInfo.getBlobKey().getKeyString() + "</blob-key>"); // Here I get no NullPointerException, blobInfo is NOT null, everything es as expected....
}
```

This works! Means the File ist stored in the Blobstore, and I get something like `<blob-key>jA_W_jiKoTpXAe9QjeFlrg</blob-key>` back from Post request.

Now I want to access this Blob with this key, but following Code results in NullPointerException, because blobInfo is null.... but why???

```
// A method from another Servlet....    
private String getData(final String blobKey) {
    //at this point blobKey is exactly that one returned previously for example jA_W_jiKoTpXAe9QjeFlrg
    try {
        final BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(new BlobKey(blobKey));

        final BlobstoreInputStream bis = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobInfo.getBlobKey()); // Here I got NullPointerException, because BlobInfo is null
        final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I would be very very glad if someone could figure out what the problem is....

Comment: You're already executing exactly the same line in your get handler, without any issues. Have you tried comparing the string you're passing in there with the one you're getting in getData? Also, please include your full stacktrace in the question.

Comment: having the same frigging problem, from com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.inputs.BlobstoreInput.createReaders()

Comment: I also have compared the strings, they're identical

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me it need only one helper class, called FileObject, which is a named dynamic byte buffer to append byte arrays:

```
public class FileObject {
    private String name;
    byte [] bufferArray = null;

    public FileObject(String name, byte[] data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bufferArray = data;
    }

    public FileObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        }

    public void appendData(byte[] data, int numberOfBytes) {

        if (bufferArray == null)
        {
            this.bufferArray = new byte [numberOfBytes];
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, bufferArray, 0, numberOfBytes);
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] tempArray = new byte[bufferArray.length + numberOfBytes];
            System.arraycopy(bufferArray, 0, tempArray, 0, bufferArray.length);
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, tempArray, bufferArray.length, numb    erOfBytes);    
            bufferArray = tempArray;
        }
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return bufferArray;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.bufferArray = data;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This is the core method to write into the file object:

```
public synchronized static byte[] readBlob(BlobKey blobKey) throws BlobServiceException{
        int bufferSize = MAX_READ_BUFFER_SIZE;
        FileObject fileObject = new FileObject("");
        try{
            AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(blobKey);
            FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
            // write the files to the disk
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
            int numberOfBytes;
            while ((numberOfBytes = readChannel.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
                fileObject.appendData(byteBuffer.array(), numberOfBytes);
                byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
            }

            readChannel.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            BlobServiceException blobIoException = new BlobServiceException("Failure while reading blob.\n" + e.getMessage());
            blobIoException.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
            throw blobIoException;
        }
        return fileObject.getData();
    }
```